# Angular y google maps seleccionar ciudad, conforme se selecciona la ciudad

Tags: angular, google-maps

Tengo un problema, un poco curioso, resulta que tengo implementado Google maps en Angular, con su respectivo buscador, pero resulta que se puede buscar por castellano o valenciano(Valencia), cuando buscas en valenciano y selecciona la palabra automáticamente,te modifica el nombre a castellano, lo selecciones en Castellano o en Valenciano.
Adjunto el código.

```
 this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      //this.setCurrentLocation();
      this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      document.getElementById('searchMap');
      //let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchMap'),{ types:['address']});
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchMap') );
      autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': [this.listCountry] });
      //autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': [this.listCountry.toLowerCase()]});
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed",  () => {
        this.ngZone.run(async () => {
          //get the place result
  
          let place: any = autocomplete.getPlace();
          //console.log("place",place.formatted_address);
          this.mymodel = place.formatted_address;
          
          /*
          * para dividir la cadena de texto y obtener el nombre
          */
          if ( place.formatted_address.includes(',') ) {
            console.log('place',place);
            
              let dividirCadena = place.formatted_address.trim().split(',');
              /*
              *  Para quitar los números del código postal
              */
              dividirCadena[0] = dividirCadena[0].replace(/[0-9]+.\s+/, "");            
            
              this.manifestations.patchValue({
                city: dividirCadena[0],
                search: dividirCadena[0],
                /* search: dividirCadena[0] */
              });
          } else { 
            this.manifestations.patchValue({
              city: place.formatted_address,
              search: place.formatted_address 
            });
          }
          
          
          //verify result
         
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }
          
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
  
          
         
          this.manifestations.patchValue({
            location: this.latitude+","+this.longitude
          })
          this.zoom = 14;
        });
      });

   
    }).catch(error => {

    });
```

codigo en app.module.ts

```
 AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      libraries:['places'],
 
    }),
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar o si esta pregunta ya se ha realizado, me pueda guiar un poco, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, después de intentar encontrar la solución, era más fácil de lo que me esperaba.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="searchMap" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Nearest Location"
                    autocorrect="off" formControlName="city" aria-label="Search Nearest Location" autocapitalize="off"
                    spellcheck="off" type="text" #searchm mdbInput (focusout)="focusOutFunction($event)">
```

Ts

```
focusOutFunction( event ) {
  // console.log('event target value ', event.target.value);
  let place: any = event.target.value;
         
  this.mymodel = place;
  
  /*
  * para dividir la cadena de texto y obtener el nombre
  */
  if ( place.includes(',') ) {
    // console.log('place',place);
    
      let dividirCadena = place.trim().split(',');
      /*
      *  Para quitar los números del código postal
      */
      dividirCadena[0] = dividirCadena[0].replace(/[0-9]+.\s+/, "");            
    
      this.manifestations.patchValue({
        city: dividirCadena[0],
        search: dividirCadena[0]

      });
  } else { 
    this.manifestations.patchValue({
       city: place,
       search: place 
    });
  }
  



}
```

Ahora el la variable se actualiza aquí y no en autocomple.
Espero que alguien le sirva.
Saludos.